# How to check if file has been closed? python3

Tags: python-3.x

Im looking for a way to check if file is now closed (you know for sure that he was opened before).
Also Im need that the checking process will keep hapening until the file is actually closed by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a context manager:

```
with open("/some/file.txt") as fin:
    text = fin.read()

    # Do stuff, possibly involving user input

print("File is now closed.")
```

The `with` arranges for `fin.close()` to be called upon exiting
that code block.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked well.